# iphone how to release memory in this case

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

I have a method like this

```
- (NSDictionary *)getCellValuesForRow:(int)row {
NSMutableDictionary *dictValues= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

Outage *outage = [listOutage objectAtIndex:row];

[dictValues setObject:outage.duration forKey:@"OutageDuration"];
   return dictValues;
```

}

and this value is stored in this way

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self getCellValuesForRow:(indexPath.row-1)]];
```

how to release memory in this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should autorelease dictValues in getCellValuesForRow, or just don't alloc it. This will keep it autoreleased:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictValues= [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

In most cases it should be the responsibility of whatever calls it to alloc it (if it needs to be kept around after the autorelease pool is cleared), then dealloc it later.

If whatever calls it doesn't need it kept around, it can just leave it autoreleased.

Answer (score 2):

This is what `autorelease` is for.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictValues= [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to simply use

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictValues= [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

That's effectively the same thing as what Dan suggested. Just less typing.

It applies to your next line, too:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self getCellValuesForRow:(indexPath.row-1)];
```